# Google App Engine: Query.GeoRegion.Rectangle Intersection

Tags: google-app-engine, intersection

Can anybody suggest an elegant, robust method for finding the intersection of two `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.GeoRegion.Rectangle` objects? Current thinking is to re-implement `java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.intersect()`.